# Use Stripe Connect in Test Mode

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am using Stripe Connect to connect through my merchant's stripe account.
I want to know is there any way to test **Stripe Connect OAuth Authentication** is testing mode or do I need to provide Real Banking information as it is giving me invalid Routing Number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you go through the OAuth flow with Stripe in Test mode, you use your Development client application id `ca_XYZ`. You then redirect the user to stripe's connect URL where they see the activation form as any real user would.

At the top though, there's a "Skip this account form" link that's only present in Test mode. This allows you to bypass the activation form. You then get redirected to your redirect_url as defined in your account settings and you can finish the connection as expected.